# How to add a CMS page to Magento in a category subdirectory rather than in the root directory?

Tags: cms, seo

Is it possible to add a CMS page to a magento store, so that the URL is as follows:

```
www.example.com/category/CMS
```

At the moment, all I seem to be able to do is:

```
www.example.com/CMS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Magento backend, go to:

```
CMS -> Pages -> Add New Page
```

On tab 'Page Information', fill in `URL Key`: "category/cms"

Add your content and visit the page on `www.yourshop.com/category/cms`

Comment: It was that easy! Thanks a lot, there's me thinking it would involve coding!